# mobx observable array flow errors

Tags: flowtype, mobx, mobx-react

I'm getting a flow error flow: property replace (Property not found in Array) when I'm calling replace on my array. How do I tell flow it is a mobx observable array? I already made the change to my flowconfig [libs] to include mobx

```
/* @flow */
import { observable } from 'mobx'

export default class GiphyStore {
  @observable images = []

  async getImageList() {
    try {
      // make axios network request
      const imgs = response.data.data.map(item => {
        return { id: item.id, url: item.images.downsized.url }
      })

      this.images.replace(imgs) // getting error???
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [test file provided by mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/2cc98ae92c56ed8f8371875436aba75657a8bab1/test/flow/test.js) you need to;

1. Use `IObservableArray<>` type for your arrays
2. Define your observable without the decorators as flow does not support them yet.

It was a joint effort of finding the answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks htkibar. I tried that, and am seeing `'identifier `IObservableArray` (Could not resolve name)' source: 'flow'. does that mean my flowconfig is not set up correctly? i posted it, but don't think that's the problem. https://gist.github.com/foobar8675/30a925e5dce8aae4da29459e1bc3cefd

Comment: Also, unfortunately, the todo store.js example uses normal js objects for flow, opposed to `IObservableArray` :(

Comment: That is interesting, could you try the updated answer? @MatthewChung

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I made the change, the error on the declaration goes away, but the original error is still there :( . Here's a screenshot. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8U02wD3-W-OY3Y1Wk04WS1xWXc

Comment: We have tried two different versions and no luck. According to [test file provided by mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/2cc98ae92c56ed8f8371875436aba75657a8bab1/test/flow/test.js) IObservableArray use should help you. Can you also provide a screenshot for that case?

Comment: Ah, the test file helped. Being a noob, I didn't think about importing the type. Also, I had to use the non-decorator way of declaring the array, again illustrated in the test file you provided.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8U02wD3-W-OUVljOXpBTUpwYTg I'm not sure how to give you credit for the right answer since it is in the comments?

Comment: I am updating the answer @MatthewChung thanks a lot :)